# The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, xubuntu

I'm having some issues installing (no dual-boot) Xubuntu (**xubuntu-20.04.2.0-desktop-amd64**) on a laptop which had Windows 10 pre-installed, but I think I did something wrong with the partitions.
When it begins to install the OS it gives me this error:

```
The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed
```

Using **fdisk -l** on Live session gives me this:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 1.49 GiB, 1584160768 bytes, 3094064 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 465.78 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD5000LPCX-2
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: FD394591-6083-4287-9631-DB029557C96F

Device       Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1     2048   1050623   1048576   512M EFI System
/dev/sda2  1050624 976771071 975720448 465.3G Linux filesystem
```

How can I sove this? Thank you.

Comment: This was new to me *Perhaps you've also heard of a file system called VFAT. VFAT is an extension of the FAT file system and was introduced with Windows 95. VFAT maintains backward compatibility with FAT but relaxes the rules. For example, VFAT filenames can contain up to 255 characters, spaces, and multiple periods.

Comment: You may want to read this *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11928982/what-is-the-difference-between-vfat-and-fat32-file-systems#:~:text=Perhaps%20you've%20also%20heard,%2C%20spaces%2C%20and%20multiple%20periods.

Comment: What you mount at /boot/efi (the EFI system partition) is normally a FAT not VFAT partition.  Probably you have to change that.  Only a few files are inside so you can backup them easily or recreate them with installer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FAT is a filetype often used by windows, but also by UEFI. The first you have replaced, but the second is needed to boot the system. It's generic so Ubuntu can install a new UEFI. Windows can use the TPM chip to do a secure boot, which verifies that the windows you are running is coming from microsoft. But since your trying to run Ubuntu, which isn't using the same keys.

Secure boot is a function you may need to switch off. You can do that in the 'bios' by booting into it using F2, F10, DEL or anything shown in the first seconds of switching on the PC. Make sure the PC is switched off fully, there are some fast boot states where it will jump straight over the BIOS selection

If that doesn't work I would wipe the harddisk clean and start the installation of Ubuntu from the beginning. So if you really don't need anything from disk SDA you can boot into the Ubuntu installer and then jump to a terminal (press ALT+F1 or CTRL+ALT+F1 or use F2 through F6).

You can delete all the partitions if you run fdisk on /dev/sda and delete and write the new partition table to the disk.

alternative fdisk programs are called cfdisk, sfdisk, cgdisk and sgdisk. For me cgdisk would be the weapon of choice.

The shotgun approach to disk wiping is to write all zero's to the first few sectors, effectively wiping all previous partition tables and file structures.

Here writing all zeros over the current efi and a bit over.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda bs=1M count=528
```