# How can I install Ubuntu in a laptop with ATA disk?

Tags: system-installation

I started to install Ubuntu from USB pen-drive, all was going well letting the installation program to make the decisions. But after setting my geographical address did appear the following message:
"The attempt to mount a file system partition type vfat in SCSI1 (0,0,0) partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed.".
When gave me the option to abort or continue... I chose to continue, and it was running for a whole day doing nothing...
I aborted.
And I don't know what to do to install Ubuntu.

My laptop is Asustek Computer X555QA with 8GB RAM, processor AMD A12-9720p radeon, and 128 GB disk. No other disks connected.

Device information: (from Gparted)
Model: ATA Sandisk SD9SB8W1, serial 184902A00DF2, Size: 119.24 GiB, Path: /dev/sda
Partition table: gpt, Heads: 255, Cylinders: 490332, Ttal sectors: 250069680, sector size: 512
BIOS information:
Disk: (same as Gparted information)
SATA Mode: AHCI (can be change to IDE)
UEFI network stack: disable (can be change to enable)

Comment: Can you boot to the Live USB session, start Gparted, and copy off the properties of the physical drive you're installing to?  Once done, please [edit] that into the question.  Also, what option (one of the "guided" or "Manual") did you choose for partition setup, and if Manual, how did you set up partitions and select them for mounting and formatting?

Comment: What is "SCSI disk"? Is it from 1994?

Comment: After googling for the laptop I found out that the harddrive is an 1TB Toshiba MQ01ABD100. This is a SATA2 drive. Not a SCSI drive. Notebookcheck.net however states a 256 GB drive. Can you give us information to what harddrive you have in there? Personally I think there is no SCSI drive in a notebook. You should have a SATA drive in it.

Comment: @Joepie Es and @ mikewhatever. I think you are right. In a modern netbook there should not be a SCSI drive. It should be a SATA drive. In this case apparently a 128 GB ( guess an SSD ).

Comment: Ubuntu Ubiquity installer wants an ESP - efi system partition (FAT32 with boot,esp flags) on first drive. So if not installing to first drive, you have to do a work around or have an ESP on first drive for it to work.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379
Others suggest disconnecting all other drives physically or logically in UEFI settings, so install drive is first drive.
Or removing boot flag/esp flag from first drive, so only ESP is install drive.

Comment: All of you are right. I was deceive by the text of the error message into believe that was a SCSI disk, I already edit the question and added information that you asked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The attempt to mount a file system with type vfat in SCSI1 (0,0,0), partition #1 (sda) at /boot/efi failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331303/the-attempt-to-mount-a-file-system-with-type-vfat-in-scsi1-0-0-0-partition-1)

Comment: Interesting to know about the secure boot. It was enabled, I disable it.

Comment: The installation program still cannot continue, it suggested me to use the partitioning menu in order to continue, I am not going to do that without guidance. Before learning about partitioning I am going to try the formatting process suggested in your link.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED!
I successfully installed Ubuntu in two easy steps, thanks to Karel:
Step 1: In BIOS turn Secure Boot to disable.
Step 2: In Geparted - Device - Create a Partition Table.
After that Install Ubuntu with no other problem.
thank you very much!